# JQuery UI Datapicker : How to add next/previous year buttons

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I use the feature of selecting a year with a dropdown. I use it to set birthdays of people at least 18 years old. So far it works perfectly. I have set it up using theseg parameters:

```
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
                    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                    minDate: '-100Y',
                    maxDate: '-18Y'
    });
```

However I'd like to have year navigation. Is it possible to add a next/previous year button?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check this : http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/dropdown-month-year.html
its part of datepicker plug in

```
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
   changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true
  });
 });
```

Comment: Like the code of the op shows that's already in my parameter list which gives me i a working dropdown. However I want buttons added for quickly changing years (like it has for the months).

I find having just the year dropdown is not always convenient enough.

Comment: in example there is month and year combo with the previous next button -- what else you want ?

Comment: The next/prev button navigates by month, not by year.

Comment: than you can go for this plug in : http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/ where functionality change by year

Comment: I did not switch to that particular library since i already need to include jqueryui for other widgets. However, the posted alternative library seems a viable option otherwise hence I accepted.

Comment: Actually datepicker accept edit date(if your field is not readonly as mine before) so user can select which date he wants, and also you can only select date from date component so it prevents invalid date submit.

Answer (score 0):

In order to complete the @PranayRana's answer, jQuery UI gives you the possibility to select the year with the option `changeYear`, and you are also able to specify the date range to your datepicker (for a `birth date` field for example).

Here's an example :

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    changeYear: true, // Add the ability to select the year
    yearRange: '1930:2000', // Set the year range selection from 1930 to 2000
});
```