# jquery datepicker - how to show prev next year buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have seen some threads on allowing the ability to have year selections on jquery datepicker. But they show how to enable combo box selection of years. But here is the kind of thing I wish to have.

< 2012 > < september >

so the less than and greater than symbols are buttons. Here is the idea I have and what I tried. Now let's say by some css and js I have the above html layout and the prev and next year buttons have classes jsPrevYear and jsNextYear. What I want to know is if I can write some code that handles the event of these two buttons?

Comment: You are missing some code

Comment: _"What I want to know is if I can write some code that handles the event of these two buttons?"_ Well, some of us can. Whether you can or can't remains to be seen since you posted no code. If, on the other hand, you're passive aggressively looking for someone else to do the work for you, then good luck.

Comment: fyi I may not be expecting much code.. something like $(".jsPrevYear").live("click", function(){//dp.moveBackAYear();}); can you be a little nicer?

Comment: Sorry, I re-read that and see how that might come off a little harsh. However, you need to try something first, and post the code here.

Comment: But you have posted neither HTML not JS

Comment: Per my duplicate link, look at the first answer. That will put you on the right path: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11630055/132528